# Configure Angular asset url dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7

Hi i am using angular 7 and i have problem with the production build of the application. My application lies in a subfolder in the server namely www.hshsh.com/**cm/** where cm is my subfolder where the built files are kept. I have set the base href as

```
--base-href = /cm/
```

Everything works fine when it comes to downloading the js files and routing. But i have a problem with displaying the images from asset folder as

```
<img src="../../assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px" >
```

It shown 404 error.

**What i have tried**

I have tried all below posibilities

```
<img src="../../assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px" >
<img src="/assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px" >
<img src="assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px" >
```

Also i have tried the css way of doing it

```
.class1 {
    background: url("/assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px""); // Doesnt work.404
}

.class2 {
    background: url("assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px""); // Compiler error
}

.class3 {
    background: url("/../../assets/images/delete_icon.png" width="15px" height="15px"" width="15px" height="15px""); // 404
}
```

None of the methods work. How can i configure the asset path without appending the baseUrl manually as

```
Base+asset+imagePath
```

Please help. I am stuck.

Comment: assets are relative to the `index.html` file. Once built, it should be `assets/...`. Just make sure that once compiled, your assets are duplicated in your dist folder. If not, check your angular.json file.

Comment: In your index.html  file  add  <base href="/applicationname/"> under the <head> .

application name is the folder where the index.html resides in.

Comment: @Maryannah Yeah. the files are geting copied. But when i do assets/.., in the network tab request is sent as www.asd.com/assets. Should not it be www.asd.com/cm/assets as i have specified the base href as /cm/

Comment: @JavaMain I am already doing that

Comment: Then try with `./assets/...`. Make it relative to the current path you're on

Comment: then  use  ./assets/ it should work

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `./assets/` for the path.

Also you need to make sure that assets is mentioned in `angular.json` under `build --> options`:

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Comment: How can I make this dynamic for the angular.json as I have a bunch of various folders in src/assets but each folder is for a specific build of the application. Right now all of the configurations are being pushed in all builds. I only want a certain folder for a certain build to be included from the src/assets folder.